# n-ary Cartesian product inRxJava

Tags: java, math, rx-java, rx-java2

Now I hold an `Observable<Observable<Integer>`, how can I transfer it into `Observable<int[]>` that contains the n-ary Cartesian product?

For example:

```
Observable<Observable<Integer> ob = Observable.just(
  Observable.just(0,1),
  Observable.just(2,3),
  Observable.just(4,5)
  );
ob...... ->   (0,2,4), (0,3,4), (0,2,5), (0,3,5), (1,2,4), (1,3,4), (1,2,5), (1,3,5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a fixed number of input `Observable`s. Second, there is no need for blocking but there is likely the need for caching because the 2nd, 3rd etc `Observable`s need to be consumed multiple times.

```
import java.util.*;

import io.reactivex.Observable;

public class Cartesian {

    static Observable<int[]> cartesian(Observable<Observable<Integer>> sources) {
        return sources.toList().flatMapObservable(list -> cartesian(list));
    }

    static Observable<int[]> cartesian(List<Observable<Integer>> sources) {
        if (sources.size() == 0) {
            return Observable.<int[]>empty();
        }
        Observable<int[]> main = sources.get(0).map(v -> new int[] { v });

        for (int i = 1; i < sources.size(); i++) {
            int j = i;
            Observable<Integer> o = sources.get(i).cache();
            main = main.flatMap(v -> {
                return o.map(w -> {
                    int[] arr = Arrays.copyOf(v, j + 1);
                    arr[j] = w;
                    return arr;
                });
            });
        }

        return main;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cartesian(Observable.just(
            Observable.just(0, 1), 
            Observable.just(2, 3), 
            Observable.just(4, 5)
        ))
        .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating Cartesian product in an asynchronous way is hard or in some sense is impossible. And if blocking is OK, you can do something like this

```
public class Main
{

    static class ProductIterator<T> implements Iterator<T[]>
    {
        private final List<List<T>> componentsList;
        private final Class<T> componentClass;
        private final int[] indices;
        private boolean hasNext;

        public ProductIterator(List<List<T>> componentsList, Class<T> componentClass)
        {
            this.componentsList = componentsList;
            this.componentClass = componentClass;
            this.indices = new int[componentsList.size()];
            this.hasNext = this.indices[componentsList.size() - 1] < componentsList.get(componentsList.size() - 1).size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return hasNext;
        }

        @Override
        public T[] next()
        {
            T[] res = (T[]) Array.newInstance(componentClass, componentsList.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < componentsList.size(); i++)
            {
                res[i] = componentsList.get(i).get(indices[i]);
            }

            // move next
            indices[0]++;
            for (int i = 0; i < componentsList.size() - 1; i++)
            {
                if (indices[i] == componentsList.get(i).size())
                {
                    indices[i] = 0;
                    indices[i + 1]++;
                }
            }
            hasNext = indices[componentsList.size() - 1] < componentsList.get(componentsList.size() - 1).size();

            return res;
        }
    }

    public static <T> Observable<T[]> product(Observable<Observable<T>> components, Class<T> componentClass)
    {
        return Observable.fromIterable(new Iterable<T[]>()
        {
            @Override
            public Iterator<T[]> iterator()
            {
                // postpone blocking up until iterator is requested 
                // and by this point we can't postpone anymore 
                Single<List<List<T>>> componentsList = components.map(o -> o.toList().blockingGet()).toList();
                return new ProductIterator<T>(componentsList.blockingGet(), componentClass);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Observable<Observable<Integer>> ob = Observable.just(
                Observable.just(0, 1),
                Observable.just(2, 3),
                Observable.just(4, 5)
        );

        Observable<Integer[]> product = product(ob, Integer.class);
        product.forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
    }
}
```

It is possible to improve this code to avoid blocking but you still will have to cache all results from all `Observable`s and code will be much more complicated. Most probably is blocking is not acceptable for you, trying to get Cartesian product is bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can resolve it myself. But is there any more elegant way?
(The `toArray` method convert an `Observable<T>` to `T[]`)

```
    Observable<int[]> toObservableArray(Observable<Observable<Integer>> obs) {
        List<int[]> list = obs.map(ob -> toArray(ob)).toList().toBlocking().last();
        return Observable.create(new SyncOnSubscribe<int[], int[]>() {
            @Override
            protected int[] generateState() {
                int[] array = new int[list.size()];
                Arrays.fill(array, 0);
                return array;
            }

            @Override
            protected int[] next(int[] state, Observer<? super int[]> observer) {
                int[] next = new int[list.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < next.length; i++) {
                    next[i] = list.get(i)[state[i]];
                }
                observer.onNext(next);
                state[state.length - 1]++;
                for (int i = state.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    int delta = list.get(i).length - state[i];
                    if (delta > 0) {
                        break;
                    } else if (delta == 0) {
                        state[i] = 0;
                        if (i == 0) {
                            observer.onCompleted();
                            break;
                        }
                        state[i - 1]++;
                    }
                }
                return state;
            }
        });
    }
```